# How to add JS and CSS calling in PHTML file?

Tags: magento2, javascript, phtml

I am including JS validations in Magento, there respected .js and .css files included like:

> app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Smartwave_Porto/layout/default.xml

```
<css src="Smartwave_Porto::css/index.css"/>
<script src="Smartwave_Porto::js/index.js"/>
```

and include those css, js files in :

> app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Smartwave_Porto/web/css and js

I have created a CMS Page and call the test.phtml file in cms page

I want to include css and js files in the test.phtml file but I cant.

Explain how to inlude those css and js files in .phtml file
Location of .phtml file:

> app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Smartwave_Porto/templates/test.phtml

Thanks!

Comment: You can not call js and css files in phtml files. However if you are including js and css  files in default.xml it should be available overall the frontend.

Comment: Then how, Where to call

Comment: you have already called in default.xml. So it should be available everywhere on frontend.

Comment: ok, but i want it in cms page loading to frontend

Comment: css and js are  like below (Reload the page to get source for: /magento2/js/index.js/)

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the bellow technique.

[image]

You can also get static file location url directly:-

```
$block->getViewFileUrl();
```

Comment: let us know, How to give other path here:<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $block->getUrl();?> other-path">

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $block->getUrl('css/index.css');?> ">

Comment: I was given liken lik above

Comment: $block->getUrl() will give your base path like http://www.example.com/. Other path means your css or js file folder structure after your main path.

Comment: I tried this but remain same

Answer (score 0):

You can add below code in PHTML file to call js

```
<script src="<?= $block->getViewFileUrl('Namespace_Vendorname::js/myjs.js')?>"/>
```

And to call CSS file add :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?= $block->getViewFileUrl('Namespace_Vendorname::css/mycss.css')?>">
```

`$block->getViewFileUrl('Namespace_Vendorname::js/myjs.js')` will load js from `pub/static/frontend/ThemeNamespace/ThemeName/en_US/Namespace_Vendorname/js`path.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?= $block->getViewFileUrl('css/mycss.css')?>">
```

Above code will load CSS file from `pub/static/frontend/ThemeNamespace/ThemeName/en_US/css`